# ERROR: We can't query your org. Getting this error after Authorize a Dev Hub

Tags: vs-code, authorization, dev-hub, sfdx-error

so, I'm pretty new to salesforce development and I got this error while trying to Authorize a Dev Hub, I already enabled the Dev Hub and I couldn't find anything anywhere to solve this error.

Also, I should have admin right as the org is a Trailhead playground.

I already tried ignoring it but I'm pretty sure it's going to be a problem in the near future, i also logged out and tried to log in again to find the same error.

Here you have a screenshot of the error.

[image: After Successfully authorized on web browser]

Answer (score 0):

Logging into the `DevHub` won't activate the SOQL Builder. You will need to do an 'SFDX: Authorize an org' as well to make sure you are logged in and a default org is set for the SOQL Builder to work.

Check [here](https://youtu.be/t4hBvzyh3SE?t=116) for info on how to perform authorization to make sure your VSCode is connected to the Salesforce org.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohith! Will try it out